# How to make a declaration of a instance with parameter?

Tags: c++

That's all my code

```
class A{
public:
    A(int x){}
};


int main() {

    A a;   // error c2512 : no appropriate default constructor available
    if (4>3) a=A(3);
    else     a=A(4);
    //and then do something with instance "a"
    return 0;
}
```

I wanna make a declaration of a instance ,and use it
What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Why do you have a single argument constructor? You don't appear to be using the argument at all. Also why are you doing `if (4>3)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve the compiler error, you would have to add a [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) (one taking no arguments) to `A`, eg:

```
class A{
public:
    A(){}
    A(int x){}
};
```

Or:

```
class A{
public:
    A() = default; // C++11 and later only
    A(int x){}
};
```

Or, you can use your existing [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) and just make its argument optional so it can also act as a default constructor, eg:

```
class A{
public:
    A(int x = 0){}
};
```

If you don't want to change `A` to support default construction, you can accomplish what you want by using the [`?:` conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) when constructing an `A` object, eg:

```
int main() {
    A a = (4 > 3) ? A(3) : A(4);
    //and then do something with instance "a"
    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```
int main() {
    A a( (4 > 3) ? 3 : 4 );
    //and then do something with instance "a"
    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you don't want to use the operator, then just save the desired value to another variable first, and then pass that to your constructor, eg:

```
int main() {
    int x;
    if (4 > 3) x = 3; else x = 4;
    A a(x);
    //and then do something with instance "a"
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have some user-defined constructors, then the compiler no longer provides the default constructor.

To be able to default construct an object, you will need to reinstate the default constructor, like this:

```
class A{
public:
    A(int x){}
    A() = default;  //  <-- here
};
```